# How to send Json-rpc via retrofit2?

Tags: android, request, retrofit2, json-rpc

I tried send `json-rpc` via `retrofit2`.
This is my interface:

```
public interface ApiInterfaceJson {

@POST
@Headers( "Content-Type: application/json" )
Call<String> getDataJson(
         @Url String url,
         @Body RequestBody body);
```

}

Create `retrofit`:

```
retrofitJson = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
            .baseUrl("http://localhost:8800")
            .client(client)
            .build();

    apiInterfaceJson   = retrofitJson.create(ApiInterfaceJson.class);
```

Call:

```
JSONObject paramObject = new JSONObject();
    try {
        paramObject.put("id", "0");
        paramObject.put("name", "user");
        paramObject.put("command", "finish");
    }catch(Exception e){
    }   
  RequestBody requestBody=  RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json"), paramObject.toString());       
MinersMonitorApplication.getApiJson().getDataJson("http://10.10.10.230:10000", requestBody).enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<String> call, @NonNull Response<String> response) {}              
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
            }
        });
```

The result is `SocketTimeoutException`.

Answer (score 0):

You need RPC wrapped retrofit - https://github.com/segmentio/retrofit-jsonrpc

Also let service see that it should use json RPC by annotating:

```
interface MultiplicationService {
    @JsonRPC("Arith.Multiply") @POST("/rpc")
    Call<Integer> multiply(@Body MultiplicationArgs args);
}
```

Note that Retrofit is only REST Based library.

Comment: Next time raise a mod flag to have your original answer undeleted when you've edited it, rather than post a new answer.